# In notepad++, what is the difference between remove empty lines and remove empty lines (containing blank characters)?

Tags: notepad++, blank-line

This is under line operations. Sounds like the same thing to me, confusing. Seems like am empty line is made up of blank characters.

Comment: The first only removes lines which does not have any content at all, whitespace or otherwise.

Comment: An empty line could be, for example, `\n\n` or `\n    \n`

Answer (score 0):

An empty line is a line having no characters at all. A line with blank characters is a  line that has only horizontal whitespace symbols.

If you use *Remove Empty Lines*, these lines- 
[image] and [image] - won't get removed.

When you use *Remove Empty Line (Containing Blank Characters)*, those lines will be deleted.

**NOTE**: *Remove Empty Line (Containing Blank Characters)* won't remove a line with blank Unicode spaces, e.g. a non-breaking U+0160 space. You'd need to use `^\s*$\R*` regex to remove such lines.